# how can write this formula in python?

Tags: python

how can i write a function  that takes 2 integer parameters, a and b.
Inside the function I need calculate the value of x using the formula below (where the term 2a indicates that 2 is multiplied by a). 
I'm quite lost with doing this can someone please give me a hint on how to start this code in python?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MSjH.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
def x(a, b):
    return (b+(b**2-1)**0.5)/(2*a)
```

In python, we use `**` for power symbols.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below method to achieve your goal.

```
# remember to import math
x = lambda a, b: (math.sqrt(b**2 - 1) + b)/(2 * a)
```

Now you can use this function:

```
x(5, 10) # gives 1.99498743710662 (roughly)
```

Comment: Astik, try to keep four spaces at the start of the lines that you want code-highlighted (and a blank line before), your answers will look a lot better. If you edit your answer, you'll see that those are the changes I made (formatting only).

Comment: Got it paxdiablo, Thanks for this sharing.